# Getting a value and subtract by value in a static column (Mean) over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample dataframe from which I want to get a value and then subtract by value in a static column (Mean) over multiple columns.

For example:

I have a dataframe df:

```
LK   Loc1  Loc2  Loc3   Mean
1     1    2     0      3  
2     2    8     4      4.6    
3     3    1     2      2    
4     2    0     1      1.5    
5     1    2     0      1.5
```

I want to get in a new dataframe:

```
 LK     Loc1    Loc2   Loc3    
  1     -2      -1     -3          
  2     -2.6    3.4    -0.6          
  3     1       -1     0          
  4     0.5     -1.5   -0.5          
  5     -0.5    0.5    -1.5
```

I tried something with:

```
df2 <- df  %>% 
  mutate(across(-LK, ~ accumulate(., `-`)))
```

But I don't know how to continue..

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this what you are after `sweep(df[, 2:4], 2, df[, 5], "-")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dply)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Loc"), ~ .x - Mean))

  LK Loc1 Loc2 Loc3 Mean
1  1 -2.0 -1.0 -3.0  3.0
2  2 -2.6  3.4 -0.6  4.6
3  3  1.0 -1.0  0.0  2.0
4  4  0.5 -1.5 -0.5  1.5
5  5 -0.5  0.5 -1.5  1.5
```

We can also use `pmap` from `purrr` package function. This is a bit complicated but it would nice to know. We use `pmap` function to iterate over every row of a data frame:

- Here we use `c(...)` to capture all values in each row but I selected only those whose names start with `Loc` as a vector of 3 elements
- Then we subtract each element of the resulting vector from the corresponding value of `Mean` variable which is represented by `..5` in this case as the fifth variable in this data set.
  The rest is just renaming and resetting the configuration of variables.

```
df %>%
  pmap_df(~ {x <- c(...)[startsWith(names(df), "Loc")]; 
  x - ..5}) %>%
  bind_cols(df$LK) %>%
  rename(LK = ...4) %>%
  relocate(LK)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
     LK  Loc1  Loc2   Loc3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1  -2    -1   -3    
2     2  -2.6   3.4 -0.600
3     3   1    -1    0    
4     4   0.5  -1.5 -0.5  
5     5  -0.5   0.5 -1.5
```

Comment: Oh my pleasure. Like the previous question you don't need to use `accumulate` here as it is just simple subtraction case.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get what you needed using `mutate_at`:

```
df %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Loc")), ~ .-Mean) %>% 
  select(-c(Mean))
```

Here, I leverage `vars(starts_with("Loc"))` to tell R that any column starting with `"Loc"` should be included in the aggregation, which is referenced as `.` after the tilde. Then I specifically refer to the column `Mean`. I noticed that the first value in the `Mean` column is not a mean across the rows, but the rest look like they are row-wise means. I wasn't sure if that was on purpose or not, but here is one code option that will get you row-wise means in dplyr: `mutate(Mean = mean(c(Loc1, Loc2, Loc3)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
read_table('LK   Loc1  Loc2  Loc3   Mean
1     1    2     0      3  
2     2    8     4      4.6    
3     3    1     2      2    
4     2    0     1      1.5    
5     1    2     0      1.5')


cbind( df[1],
       map_dfc(select(df,starts_with('Loc')), ~ .x - df$Mean) )
#>   LK Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
#> 1  1 -2.0 -1.0 -3.0
#> 2  2 -2.6  3.4 -0.6
#> 3  3  1.0 -1.0  0.0
#> 4  4  0.5 -1.5 -0.5
#> 5  5 -0.5  0.5 -1.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>